# PTAM to reconstruct scene

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Do anyone of you know how to reconstruct scene model/area from the information obtained from **PTAM** (using point cloud maybe) or any visual slam algo like **RGBD SLAM** or **V-Slam**.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51424/ptam-to-reconstruct-scene/) by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to try the Multiresolution Surfel Map package available on
code.google.com/p/mrsmap

It performs RGB-D-SLAM in real time on a CPU.
For details see this paper:
[www.ais.uni-bonn.de/papers/JVCI_13_RGB-D-SLAM.pdf](http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/papers/JVCI_13_RGB-D-SLAM.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [Sven Behnke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4059/sven-behnke/) with karma: 43 on 2013-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_NOOB_CYBORG](https://answers.ros.org/users/3275/ros_noob_cyborg/) on 2013-01-27**:
I'll take a look at it, thanks!